# Custom bar button item not performing segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have a right bar button item as defined in my viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIButton *helpButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:helpButton ];

}
```

I had linked the bar button item and performed segue with identifier but it's not pushing the view. Why is that so?

```
- (IBAction)btnShowHelp:(id)sender {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showHelp" sender:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete the link between your button and `- (IBAction)btnShowHelp:(id)sender`, change your method to `- (void)btnShowHelp(id)sender`, then change your code in `viewDidLoad` like this :

```
    UIButton *helpButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
    [helpButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnShowHelp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:helpButton ];
```

Comment: Make a suggestion：Try not to use XIB，use code to implementation what effect you want.

Comment: Thanks! Just figured it out the same time as you haha

Comment: you could suggest that adding target using `addTarget ..` method only makes link between a button and actual view.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `btnShowHelp` that was in my storyboard was already replaced by the new UIButton defined in viewDidLoad and there was no need for it.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617151-initwithcustomview?language=objc

> The bar button item created by this method does not call the action method of its target in response to user interactions. Instead, the bar button item expects the specified custom view to handle any user interactions and provide an appropriate response.

I was doing `[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setAction:]` which I then realised I was suppose to **set the action for my UIButton instead of the bar button item**...

```
UIButton *helpButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[helpButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showHelp) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:helpButton ];

- (void)showHelp {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showHelp" sender:self];
}
```

[Adding action and target to a custom Navigation BarButtonItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979385/adding-action-and-target-to-a-custom-navigation-barbuttonitem)